# Given an ODE equation, define ODE of inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have an ODE equation of the form 
$$tu'(t)=a+(t-b)u(t)-tu^2(t), $$
with the solution being a decently ugly function. Defining $h(\cdot)=u(\cdot)^{-1}$, i.e. its inverse which exists, is it possible to define similar ODE for the function $h(\cdot)$ just from the given equation?

On one hand I do not see how, on the other hand the ODE contains the information about the function which contains the info defining the inverse.

Comment: Do you know what inverse function is? In this case it's $t(u)$, which means $$u'(t)=\frac{1}{t'(u)}$$ Now substitute this into your equation and see what happens

Comment: No it is not known, I would just like to define it in terms of ODE as with the $u(t)$.

Comment: Or did you mean the reciprocal function $h=\frac1u$? As this is not a Bernoulli equation, that will not work. Setting $u=\frac{v'}{v}$ will transform this into a second order linear ODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$t\frac{du}{dt}=a+(t-b)u-tu^2 $$

$$\frac{dt}{du}=\frac{t}{a+(t-b)u-tu^2}$$

The ODE for $t(u)$ is :

$$t'(u)=\frac{t(u)}{a-bu+ut(u)-u^2 t(u)}$$
Note that this transformation doesn't simplify the problem of solving the equation.

The original ODE is a Riccati ODE. If you want to solve it for an explicit solution (which involves some special functions), use the standard method for solving the Riccati ODEs.

Comment: Hi Jean ! I wonder if the equation could be something else. What is amazing is that the original one has an explicit solution but not the transformed one (as you wrote). Cheers

Comment: Hi Claude ! The solution of the original equation is a non-linear combination of confluent hypergeometric functions and Laguerre functions. It is not surprising that the inverse function has no explicit form with the presently available special functions. Even the inverse of some standard functions are not explicit. Furthermore the inverse of non-linear combination of special functions have few chance to be explicit. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I know; this is what I got and why I wonder zbout the question.